# Check if a segment line intersects a triangle (and how to get the point where it happens)

Tags: geometry, vectors

A point is (x,y,z)

A segment is defined using two points.

A triangle is defined using three points, and here we consider the plane that's bounded by those three points.

How can I get the point (if any) where the segment intersects the triangle?

Or in other words, check if the segment goes through the plane created by the triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this paper, which represents more or less the state of the art...

[http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/courses/2003/ImageSynthesis/papers/Acceleration/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517125238/http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/courses/2003/ImageSynthesis/papers/Acceleration/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf)

Comment: Crap, I thought this was an easy geometry question. Thanks!

Comment: @FeloVilches It comes down to less than 40 lines of C code. As graphics/geometry problems go, that's very simple.

Comment: By the way, asking for "the point" where they intersect is a mistake, for the line might lie in the plane of the triangle, in which case the intersection might consist of an entire line segment.

Comment: +1 for the reference. I was going to guess barycentric coordinates :)

Comment: @FeloVilches The technique in paper computes the intersection for a ray. Since you’re got a line segment, you’ll also have to test that the line segment actually intersects the triangle’s plane in the first place (and in the case that it’s in the plane, intersects the triangle).

Comment: Right. A good first step, if you have a point $P$ on the plane and a unit normal vector $n$, is to compute $(P-A)\cdot n$ and $(P-B) \cdot n$ for your endpoints $A$ and $B$. If both are positive or both are negative, there's no intersection. If exactly one is zero, check whether that point's in the triangle. If both are zero, you check the segment-triangle intersection in the plane. And if they have opposite signs, apply Moller-Trumbore to the ray starting at $A$ in direction $B-A$.